# EMR bootstrap installing python modules - bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code

Tags: pyspark, sh, amazon-emr

I am trying to install python modules through the EMR Console bootstrap actions by following these steps:

1. Uploading a file to: `s3://mybucket/bootstrap/install_python_modules.sh` containing the following script:
   `#!/bin/sh
   set -e -x
   sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
   sudo easy_install pip 
   sudo pip install -U pandas`
2. Adding a bootstrap action in the console (Custom action) with the following script location: `s3://mybucket/bootstrap/install_python_modules.sh` and with the following name: 
   "*Install python Modules*"
   [Check this step in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfzdV.jpg)

The cluster gets terminated with the following error:
*On the master instance (i-0c8dffa0aa85c8b62), bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code*

Comment: Can you provide the log output? Should be stored in `{your_log_path}/{job_id}/node/{node_id}/bootstrap-actions/1 as stderr and stdout files